# Passed C# object to a function and tried to initialize values using deSerializer. The changes are not reflected outside the function

Tags: c#, serialization, binaryformatter

```
 public Reporter(String filePath, FileType type)
            {
                PropRnW = new PropertyFileReader(filePath, type, this);
            }   


public PropertyFileReader(String filePath, FileType type, Reporter reporter)
            {
                OriginalPath = filePath;
                Type = type;
                this.Read(reporter);
            } 

private void Read(Reporter m_reporter)
    {
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        Stream stream = new FileStream(SavePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        m_reporter = (Reporter)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        stream.Close();
    }
```

I checked the value of m_reporter in the function and the values are reflected accurately. Though when i check the values once outside the function they are not changed.

Comment: Perhaps sharing some more of the code outside the function,  where you said the object is unchanged, will help

Comment: Deserialization will get the value if the serialized data contains it, check what you are serializing

Comment: I am getting the values when deserialized in m_reporter. But as soon as i am outside the function scope; the values are back to original(default) @MrinalKamboj

Comment: I have added some code which leads to the read function; I hope this helps. @Menahem

Comment: what is `Reporter` here? is it a `struct`?

Comment: No, it is a class. @MarcGravell

Comment: Sorry, made some changes in code; I mixed up two versions in which names were bit different. Now the code is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with my code was that I was trying to assign a new instance to Reporter object in Read method:

```
m_reporter = (Reporter)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
```

i.e. Deserialize returns a new instance of an object. This new instance is assigned in Read method and thus is available in the scope of Read method. It treats m_reporter as a local variable. Thus as soon as we get out of scope of Read method, reporter has its original state.

Thus, creating a property (as suggested by @Gaurav) in PropertyFileReader class and using it makes this new instance available even outside the Read method. Then we have to individually assign all the properties of property to the original instance.
So, i modified the code as below:

```
    public Reporter(String filePath, FileType type)
                {
                    PropRnW = new PropertyFileReader(filePath, type);
                    this.Property1 = PropRnW.m_reporter.Property1;
                    this.Property2 = PropRnW.m_reporter.Property2;
                }   

    class PropertyFileReader
{
    public Reporter m_reporter {get; set;}

    public PropertyFileReader(String filePath, FileType type)
                {
                    OriginalPath = filePath;
                    Type = type;
                    this.Read();
                } 

    private void Read()
        {
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            Stream stream = new FileStream(SavePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

            m_reporter = (Reporter)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            stream.Close();
        }
};
```

Comment: The issue is you are passing the m_reporter to the constructor and using it directly. Please create a property for it  in the current class and then in the constructor assign that property from reporter object and return that property from Read method and assign it to your parent class.

Comment: Isn't this going round and round! like i pass the instance to read method and then get back a object of same type(but did not get the object I passed changed) which i then assign to the object I passed. @Gaurav

Comment: I think you don't to pass that object just return  (Reporter)formatter.Deserialize(stream) from the Read method. I am not sure what's your requirement but in read method you will get new object reporter class and which is available for the current scope(read method) only.

Comment: Okay! That makes sense! It did work too...Can you please edit the answers for it to be correct and for future reference..@Gaurav

Comment: Sorry for confusion @Gaurav, I misread your comment. But that miss-interpretation led me to my answer.